# Iterate through nested JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to take some of my nested object array and push to a new JSON Array object.

I would like for each channel to take publishedTracks to a new json obj and merge them all together to a new array obj.

My JSON:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "genre_id": null,
    "genre_id_opt": null,
    "name": "channela1",
    "slug": "",
    "description": null,
    "is_verified": 0,
    "cover": null,
    "avatar": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "publishedTracks": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "album_id": 1,
            "name": "track1",
            "slug": "track1",
            "track_no": null,
            "track": null,
            "duration": 0,
            "avatar": "track_avatar1.jpg",
            "genre_id": null,
            "genre_id_opt": null,
            "is_explicit": null,
            "created_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
            "album": {
                "id": 1,
                "channel_id": 1,
                "genre_id": null,
                "genre_id_opt": null,
                "name": "alb1",
                "slug": "alb1",
                "description": "labore qui non et et ratione nobis",
                "release_date": null,
                "avatar": "alb_avatar1.jpg",
                "type": null,
                "is_publish": 1,
                "created_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z"
            },
            "_pivot_id": 1,
            "_pivot_channel_id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 27,
            "album_id": 1,
            "name": "track27",
            "slug": "track27",
            "track_no": null,
            "track": null,
            "duration": 0,
            "avatar": "track_avatar27.jpg",
            "genre_id": null,
            "genre_id_opt": null,
            "is_explicit": null,
            "created_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
            "album": {
                "id": 1,
                "channel_id": 1,
                "genre_id": null,
                "genre_id_opt": null,
                "name": "alb1",
                "slug": "alb1",
                "description": "qui non et et ratione sint officia nobis",
                "release_date": null,
                "avatar": "alb_avatar1.jpg",
                "type": null,
                "is_publish": 1,
                "created_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z"
            },
            "_pivot_id": 1,
            "_pivot_channel_id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "album_id": 14,
            "name": "track2",
            "slug": "track2",
            "track_no": null,
            "track": null,
            "duration": 0,
            "avatar": "track_avatar2.jpg",
            "genre_id": null,
            "genre_id_opt": null,
            "is_explicit": null,
            "created_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
            "album": {
                "id": 14,
                "channel_id": 1,
                "genre_id": null,
                "genre_id_opt": null,
                "name": "alb14",
                "slug": "alb14",
                "description": "aliquam odio sapiente architecto",
                "release_date": null,
                "avatar": "alb_avatar14.jpg",
                "type": null,
                "is_publish": 1,
                "created_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z"
            },
            "_pivot_id": 14,
            "_pivot_channel_id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 28,
            "album_id": 14,
            "name": "track28",
            "slug": "track28",
            "track_no": null,
            "track": null,
            "duration": 0,
            "avatar": "track_avatar28.jpg",
            "genre_id": null,
            "genre_id_opt": null,
            "is_explicit": null,
            "created_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
            "album": {
                "id": 14,
                "channel_id": 1,
                "genre_id": null,
                "genre_id_opt": null,
                "name": "alb14",
                "slug": "alb14",
                "description": "aliquam odio sapiente architecto",
                "release_date": null,
                "avatar": "alb_avatar14.jpg",
                "type": null,
                "is_publish": 1,
                "created_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z"
            },
            "_pivot_id": 14,
            "_pivot_channel_id": 1
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 1,
    "genre_id": null,
    "genre_id_opt": null,
    "name": "chann1",
    "slug": "chann1",
    "description": "adipisci non impedit tempora mollitia et est",
    "is_verified": 0,
    "cover": "chann_cover1.jpg",
    "avatar": "chann_avatar1.jpg",
    "created_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
    "publishedTracks": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "album_id": 2,
            "name": "track3",
            "slug": "track3",
            "track_no": null,
            "track": null,
            "duration": 0,
            "avatar": "track_avatar3.jpg",
            "genre_id": null,
            "genre_id_opt": null,
            "is_explicit": null,
            "created_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
            "album": {
                "id": 2,
                "channel_id": 2,
                "genre_id": null,
                "genre_id_opt": null,
                "name": "alb2",
                "slug": "alb2",
                "description": "aliquid neque autem est dignissimos",
                "release_date": null,
                "avatar": "alb_avatar2.jpg",
                "type": null,
                "is_publish": 1,
                "created_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z"
            },
            "_pivot_id": 2,
            "_pivot_channel_id": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 29,
            "album_id": 2,
            "name": "track29",
            "slug": "track29",
            "track_no": null,
            "track": null,
            "duration": 0,
            "avatar": "track_avatar29.jpg",
            "genre_id": null,
            "genre_id_opt": null,
            "is_explicit": null,
            "created_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
            "album": {
                "id": 2,
                "channel_id": 2,
                "genre_id": null,
                "genre_id_opt": null,
                "name": "alb2",
                "slug": "alb2",
                "description": "aliquid neque autem est dignissimos",
                "release_date": null,
                "avatar": "alb_avatar2.jpg",
                "type": null,
                "is_publish": 1,
                "created_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z"
            },
            "_pivot_id": 2,
            "_pivot_channel_id": 2
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "user_id": 6,
    "genre_id": null,
    "genre_id_opt": null,
    "name": "chann2",
    "slug": "chann2",
    "description": "debitis repudiandae oluptatem quod",
    "is_verified": 0,
    "cover": "chann_cover2.jpg",
    "avatar": "chann_avatar2.jpg",
    "created_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
    "publishedTracks": []
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": 3,
    "genre_id": null,
    "genre_id_opt": null,
    "name": "chann3",
    "slug": "chann3",
    "description": "rerum ut sequuntur dolores",
    "is_verified": 0,
    "cover": "chann_cover3.jpg",
    "avatar": "chann_avatar3.jpg",
    "created_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-03-06T14:32:18.000Z",
    "publishedTracks": []
}
```

]

Comment: Fantastic! What have you tried?

Comment: var obj = [];
   var i=0;
   channel.forEach(function(channel) {
    obj.push(channel[i]);
    i++;
   });

Comment: What didn't work? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This is not JSON, it's just a JavaScript array. What is your desired output?

Comment: channel[i] still adds the channel itself with the publishedTracks, while I only want to add publishedTracks on my new obj

Comment: I would like to have my new obj populated with publishedTracks elements for each parent object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
//channels is your array that you have put
var obj = [];  
channels.forEach(function(channel) { 
   // it takes publishedTracks of the channel and pushes into a separate array.        
   obj.push(channel.publishedTracks); 

   //remove from channel object
   delete channel.publishedTracks;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Please explain what you have done and why you did what you did for the OP and future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you might try

```
var newArray = JSONObject.map(function (elem) {
    return elem.publishedTracks.reduce(function(prev, current) {
      var result = prev;
      result.push(current);
      return result;
    }, []);
    });
```